# Landscape Images in the same folder

Tags: android

I have made a layout folder for landscape and what i did is make a landscape image for my first activity which looks fine. Now I would like to know is do I have to make the same LS image for the rest of my activity and put them in the same folder or keep them to thier own folder.
And does the name of the folder in my main layout have to be the same in layout-land folder

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have make them all.
you just need to make some layouts which need to show different view in land mode.

Comment: Don't get you some but not all